# Обновление кода клиентской части Android/ios

Tags: android, ios

Есть ли возможность обновлять функционал(не контент) приложений Android/ios(java/swift)? Проблема в том,что бэкендеры меняют или добавляют новые API на стороне сервера, то при изменении логики api -клиентские приложения могут упасть,так как у них описана старая логика на принятие ответа сервера,свой подход к парсингу полученных данных и т.д. Аналогично и в случае новых API, старые приложения еще не имеют функционала кода для работы с этим api. Понятно, что можно сравнивать версии сборок мобильных приложений и слать им нотификации в случае каких то обнов/изменений для скачиваний с appStore и playMarket.Но как можно удаленно синхронизировать код или размещать части кода на стороне сервера?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь про вклинивании java кода в установленную программу - никак. Исполняемый код из апк не может быть изменен никак, это сломает цифровую подпись. Прикрепить скаченную библиотеку/модуль тоже не получится, разве что с рутом есть какие-то хаки.

Есть один сложный вариант - с помощью фантастического количества работы. Вполне реально сделать движок, который читает какие-то полученные с сервера скрипты и исполняет. При первом запуске скачиваются эти скрипты, сохраняются на устройстве и потом обновляются по мере надобности.

Как вариант посмотрите в сторону [Trusted Web Activity](https://habr.com/ru/post/439238/), может так получится решить вашу задачу.